# Connect Command in Call of Duty : Black Ops 1 not Working?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I have Installed Call of Duty : Black Ops With Update 6.Now I want to Play with my brother on lan with bots.So I am using tecknogods bo loader.I start Game with bots on my laptop and without bots on Brothers laptop (launching with bo loader).On brothers laptop when i type

**\connect 192.168.1.110**         (in console)

It does nothing on enter.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a slash. Just write

```
connect 192.168.1.110
```